# How to pass Cursor variable to postgres proceudre while calling from java?

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am calling a postgres stored procedure from spring boot application which has 1 IN parameter of type text and 1 INOUT parameter of type refcursor. How to call this procedure from springboot application other than CallableStatement.

```java
public class CallProc {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, java.sql.SQLException {
        
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://azure.com/test";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user","test");
        props.setProperty("password","test");
        props.setProperty("ssl","true");
        props.setProperty("escapeSyntaxCallMode", "callIfNoReturn");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);

        // need a transaction
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        java.sql.CallableStatement callableStatement =
            conn.prepareCall("{call myProc(?, ?)}");

        callableStatement.setString(1, "user");
        callableStatement.setObject(2, null);

        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.REF_CURSOR);

        callableStatement.execute();
       
        java.sql.ResultSet rs =
            (java.sql.ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(2);

        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));

        rs.close();
        conn.commit();

        conn.close();
    }
}
```

and my procedure definition is like this,

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myapp.MyProc(
     in_user_id TEXT,
     INOUT user_roles refcursor)
language plpgsql
AS $BODY$
DECLARE

DERIVED USER_ID VARCHAR(50);

BEGIN
//body
...
//
END
$BODY$
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to call a procedure in any other way?

Comment: Becasue CallableStatement is giving org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: helloworld() is a procedure
  Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL. this error @LaurenzAlbe can check limitation of PG JDBC driver limitation here  https://www.highgo.ca/2020/11/25/calling-a-stored-procedure-in-postgrsql-from-java-and-its-current-limitations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call procedures using a `java.sql.CallableStatement`, use the connection parameter `escapeSyntaxCallMode` with the values `call` or `callIfNoReturn` and specify no return parameter. As [the documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters) says:

> **escapeSyntaxCallMode** = String
>
> Specifies how the driver transforms JDBC escape call syntax into underlying SQL, for invoking procedures or functions. In `escapeSyntaxCallMode=select` mode (the default), the driver always uses a SELECT statement (allowing function invocation only). In `escapeSyntaxCallMode=callIfNoReturn` mode, the driver uses a CALL statement (allowing procedure invocation) if there is no return parameter specified, otherwise the driver uses a SELECT statement. In `escapeSyntaxCallMode=call` mode, the driver always uses a CALL statement (allowing procedure invocation only).

The problem is that before procedures were added in v11, the JDBC driver converted a `CallableStatement` invocation to a function call, which does not work for procedures.

Here is a code sample that calls a procedure `p(IN integer, INOUT refcursor)`, where the `refcursor` is on a result set of `integer`s:

```java
public class CallProc {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, java.sql.SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        java.sql.Connection conn =
            java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql:test?user=laurenz&password=something&escapeSyntaxCallMode=callIfNoReturn"
            );

        // need a transaction
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        java.sql.CallableStatement callableStatement =
            conn.prepareCall("{call p(?::text, ?::refcursor)}");

        callableStatement.setInt(1, 5);
        callableStatement.setObject(2, null);

        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.REF_CURSOR);

        callableStatement.execute();
       
        java.sql.ResultSet rs =
            (java.sql.ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(2);

        while (rs.next())
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));

        rs.close();
        conn.commit();

        conn.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to like this  { ? = call myProc(?,?)}

Comment: I am trying like this   // myProc(IN text,INOUT refcursor)
query = "call myProc(?,?)";
CallabelStatement stmt = prepareCall(query); 
stmt.setString(1,"userID");
stmt.registerOutParameter(2,Types.REF_CUR);
here I am getting error as statement does not declare an OUT parameter
use { ? = call(?,?)query = "call myProc(?,?)";
stmt.setString(1,"userID");
stmt.registerOutParameter(2,Types.REF_CUR);
ERROR-> statement does not declare an OUT parameter
use { ? = call(?,?)

Comment: and when I try with this String query = "{ ? = call myProc(?,?)}"; 
CallabelStatement stmt = prepareCall(query);
stmt.registerOutParameter(1,Types.REF_CUR);
stmt.setString(2,"userID);
stmt.registerOutParameter(3,Types.REF_CUR);
ERROR -> function myProc does not exist.

Comment: I have revised the answer and added an example.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, even though I specified escapeSyntaxCallMode=call or escapeSyntaxCallMode=callIfNoReturn its giving error that function myProc(character varying, unknown) does not exist. No function matches the given name and arguments. add explicit type cast

Comment: Please edit your question and add the function definition. The body is not important, but the rest.

Comment: I am using the same piece of code to call stored procedure which you provided here. One thing is my db is on azure cloud does that make any difference?

Comment: I am using driver version 41.1.1 and when I tried to use latest version i.e. 42.2.23 its giving error that root.cert is not present. not able to connect to db itself.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant the definition of the database procedure.

Comment: Hi @Laurenz, I have updated the procedure defination

Comment: Perhaps you should qualify the function name with the schema: `{call myapp.myproc(?,?)}`.

Comment: for that I am executing this SET SEARCH_PATH = myapp; in the code.. That I forgot to mention..

Comment: If it truly is a type mismatch, then an explicit cast like in my updated answer will help. There are other possibilities, for example that you connect to the wrong database...